# Cordova Calendar Plugin

Tags: cordova, meteor, cordova-plugins

I am using **cordova-plugin-calendar** with my Meteor App.

But I want to cover every possible repeat aspect just like https://calendar.google.com/calendar/

Some Examples of what I looking for,

Weekly,
Particular Day of Every Week Or Like Every Second Friday.
Every Tuesday and Friday

Monthly
Particular day of month like 20th of every month
Particular day of Week of every month like Every First Friday of Month or Every First and Third Friday Month

Now, I am not sure about How to make **"Every Tuesday and Friday"** and **"Particular day of Week of every month like Every First Friday of Month or Every First and Third Friday Month"** options work with this calendar.

I am aware there is There is an recurrenceInterval option, And I can use that for "Every Second Week" and "Quarterly" Options but please guide me regarding other options.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Okay, I have an app that display list of events. When user add event in his list, It has to be sync with the calendar.

Event can be like first Friday of every month or second and fourth Saturday of every month. Or Every Tuesday and Friday.. etc..

I want to know that how to sync this type of events with the help of **cordova-plugin-calendar**